# can't set axios custom header

Tags: axios, vite

I have an axios config error : when I run vite app, I have this error : `typeError: config.headers.common is undefined` 
this is my axios config file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Ls from '@/services/ls.js'
window.Ls = Ls
window.axios = axios
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
console.log(window.axios.defaults)
window.axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const companyId = 1
  console.log(config)
  if (companyId) {
    config.headers.common['company'] = companyId
  }
  return config
})
```

The first log it hase `headers.common` but iside the interceptors function has this value :
 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`axios.defaults.headers.common` is for setting global default headers that Axios will use to composite the headers it sends with any request [ref](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults) (it combines these with other headers specified on the request etc.) In the interceptor, you are modifying the config for a specific request, so the headers have already been composited to just the `headers` field of the config and you should modify those versus modifying the global defaults within the interceptor.